# Ubuntu Touch - Dekko Email Menu Viability

Tags: ubuntu-touch, email-client

Is there a setting that I can change to select which headings I wish to see when my Dekko email is running? Currently when I have any inbox open I can see "All - Unread - Starred - Tagged - Deleted". This is fine but for me having "Sent" would be more useful than Starred or Tagged. Does anyone know how can I change the headings to what I want?

Comment: Wanting to see "Sent" messages in your inbox doesn't sound right to me. Is it about "answered" mails?

Comment: I did not say sent emails in your inbox. I meant sent as abother heading option father than tagged.

Comment: Yeah I'd love tobe able to access all my folders particularly junk

Comment: It sure would be nice for it to be changeable to what the individual user needs and wants. I will look at raising a feature request for this.

Comment: My interpretation of this "heading" is as a selection of filters. So, whatever filter you select the base set of what you see is the inbox, or whatever folder you are currently looking at. This selection of filters should not be mixed with a (customizable) navigation bar, or big confusion will result, IMHO.

Comment: I see what you are saying now. The headings (filters) that I mentioned are in the inbox. So if that is the case being able to click on Gmail rathwr than inbox woyld be good. As thia may give the customization people would want. Or the option of selecting what filters they want.